# How to select columns in editor views

Tags: eclipse

This may be a plugin/editor specific question, but I'm wondering if there is a way to select column 4-10 rows 1-10, for example in any editor or some editors within Eclipse?

Note: this can be done with Notepad++ and Vim for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Eclipse 3.5 (Galileo), you can enter rectangular selection mode by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

Comment: Interestingly, I googled "eclipse rectangular selection" only to find [this Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945382/eclipse-plugin-for-rectangular-select-cut-paste-regions) answered by... me.

Comment: what about OSX?

Comment: @Erik Vold: [This SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053725/how-do-i-enable-the-column-selection-mode-in-eclipse/3426556#3426556) says that the key combination is `Option+Command+A` on OSX.