# How to select columns in editor view for Eclipse on OSX

Tags: macos, eclipse, javascript

Same as [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/224165/how-to-select-columns-in-editor-views), but for OSX.

In short: how to I enter rectangular selection mode on OSX?

I see a button for doing this with the standard useless "text editor" that is default with eclipse, but not with the "javascript editor" which I use 99% of the time.

Answer (score 6):

Press `Command-Option-A` or click the *Toggle Block Selection Mode* button in the toolbar.

[image]

---

It looks different from Cocoa native block selection:

[image]

Comment: `command+option+a` does not work for me..

Comment: also I don't see that button..

Comment: @erikvold What version and variant of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: I am using Version: 4.2.0

Comment: @erikvold [Cannot reproduce the problem](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Wz5QP.png). Did you maybe just open a perspective that does not include this in the toolbar? Do you have an editor open (only then are these text editing buttons displayed)? Have you tried to create a new workspace to see if you just messed up your configuration? Please provide more relevant information...

Comment: this is what I see while I'm editing a file http://i.imgur.com/KtRDq.png

Comment: @erik Please consider answering all my individual questions.

Comment: I have this problem on all of my machines, I created the workspaces separately, right now I am using a comp that is only a week old, and I created a new workspace for it last week.  That is all of your questions now right?

Comment: ok so I see this button when I use the standard "text editor" but not when I use the "javascript editor" so I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel said press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>. If the button is not showing in the toolbar you can activate it with:

- Window->Customize perspective
- Command Groups Availability
- enable the Editor Presentation group.

Answer (score -1):

You can hold down <kbd>Option</kbd> while selecting, your cursor should change into a plus sign, then you can select rectangularly. This works in nearly any application, by the way.

Comment: It doesn't even work in Safari multi-line form fields. The chance it works in a Java cross-platform application is even worse.

Comment: It doesn't work in Eclipse..

Comment: this doesn't work for me